# How to create a triangle UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

How can I create a triangle UIImage? Here's how I'm doing it now, but it's not producing any image at all.

```
extension UIImage {

    static func triangle(side: CGFloat, color: UIColor)->UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: side, height: side), false, 0)
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        ctx.saveGState()

        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: side / 2, y: 0))
        ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: side, y: side))
        ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: side))
        ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: side / 2, y: 0))
        ctx.closePath()

        ctx.setFillColor(color.cgColor)

        ctx.restoreGState()
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return img
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your path does not contain any lines, so there's no region to fill. In addition you are not drawing the path.

Try something like this:

```
static func triangle(side: CGFloat, color: UIColor)->UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: side, height: side), false, 0)
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    ctx.saveGState()

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: side / 2, y: 0))
    //### Add lines
    ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: side, y: side))
    ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: side))
    //ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: side / 2, y: 0)) //### path is automatically closed
    ctx.closePath()

    ctx.setFillColor(color.cgColor)

    ctx.drawPath(using: .fill) //### draw the path

    ctx.restoreGState()
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return img
}
```

Comment: but what about the line between the two bottom points of the triangle? -- doesn't look like it was added there

Comment: @shoe - That's what `closePath` does, completing the path back to where you started it.

Comment: @Rob, but drawing a line back to where i started it would not close the triangle. what seems to be missing is the "base" of the triangle. here's how i interpreted that code -- let me know if i'm wrong -- a path begins, we move  to the top of the triangle, add a line from there to the right point of the triangle. then, still at the top of the triangle, we add another line from the top to the left point, and then the path is closed. it seems like `closePath()` is automatically adding a line between the two bottom points of the triangle. is that what's happening?

Comment: The above code does `move(to:)` to top center, `addLine(to:)` to bottom right corner, `addLine(to:)` to bottom left corner, and `closePath()` then adds the final line back to the top-center (where the path started).

Comment: @shoe, you may be mistaking about this _still at the top of the triangle_. `addLine(to:)` adds a line from the current point to the point specified, and moves the current point to the specified point. Re-read my code with this behavior in mind. But as Rob or Duncan C have shown, using `UIBezierPath` would be more general and preferred way in recent iOS programming.

Answer (score 4):

You might just use `UIBezierPath` and not use CoreGraphics at all. Furthermore, nowadays we’d use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`:

```
extension UIImage {
    static func triangle(side: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: side, height: side)).image { _ in
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: side / 2, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: side, y: side))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: side))
            path.close()

            color.setFill()
            path.fill()
        }
    }
}
```

For `UIBezierPath` version that still uses `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, see [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45113648/1) of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

OOPer told you about your lack of lines, and failure to actually draw the triangle.

In addition to that, I would suggest avoiding mucking around with graphics contexts. UIBezierPath makes it cleaner and easier to draw without having to worry about contexts. Also, you don't need to save and restore contexts since you are creating a temporary context and then immediately discarding it.

Here is a complete playground that draws your triangle (and fills and strokes the image rectangle so it's easier to see - you'd remove the stroke and probably fill the shape with `UIColor.clear` instead.)

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true


extension UIImage {

  static func triangle(side: CGFloat, color: UIColor)->UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: side, height: side), false, 0)

    //First fill the bounds with white
    let rectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: side, height: side))
    UIColor.white.setFill() //Use clear if you want your image to only contain the triangle.
    rectPath.fill()

    //Now build the triangle path
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: side / 2, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: side, y: side))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: side))
    path.close() //Closing the path draws the final line
    color.setFill()
    path.fill()

    //Stroke the outer path in gray so you can see the bounds - remove if desired
    UIColor.gray.setStroke()
    rectPath.stroke()

    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return img
  }
}

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imageView
imageView.image = UIImage.triangle(side: 200.0, color: UIColor.yellow)
```